# Show text in modern greek in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, excel-2007, non-unicode

I am working on Microsoft Office 2007 in Italian language and am building a little program for a library management with VBA including buttons, msgboxes, etc.

My issue is that I can't write in VBA code in Greek language and I can't view the msgboxes in Greek. I can do this only by putting the text in some cells and giving the value of the cell to the msgbox.

Also, when I have inputboxes with Greek characters. I do not get them correctly. I'm always viewing something like **<kbd>s??S? e??? jj?</kbd>**.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

These two may work for you:

#### Set the non-Unicode language to Greek

Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Advanced:

Set the native language for non-Unicode programs.

#### Set the font in VBA editor

VBA Editor > Tools > Options > Editor Format:

Choose a font which supports your language.

In reference to [here](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=193031).